# Refreshing javascript after jquery ajax call in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a jsp page that is refreshing periodically after 5 second to display latest data. In this page I am calling js files .
Using jquery ajax refresh i am able to refresh my server side coding but it is not affecting on the page.
I guess this is because my java scripts are not getting refreshed periodically.

Please tell me how to call javascript after jquery ajax refresh.

Below is the code i am using for the jquery java script refresh

```
<script>
            (function worker() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:8088Login.do', 
                    success: function(data) {
                       // $("#refresh").html(data);
                        // alert(data);
                    },
                    complete: function() {

                        //alert("refresh");
                        // 
                        // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
                        setTimeout(worker, 5000);
                    }
                });
            })();
        </script>
```

Comment: do you get alert if you un-comment `alert("refresh");`? do you try this : `setTimeout(function(){ worker(); },5000);` ?

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ worker(); },5000); this also i have tried alert is printing server side rfresh is also happening but data not getting refreshed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

does the solution require javascript?  you can achieve the same result using html meta tag refresh.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/F8ITSl?p=preview

Comment: Hi ..I have already tried it but each time whole page refreshes but i need only data to be refreshed .without any loading symbol.I mean data should not blink

Comment: right, it's because the meta tag causes your browser to periodically refresh the entire page.  regarding your javascript ajax issue, like what Adrian mentioned, your url seems to be incorrect.  i think it should be http://localhost:8088/Login.do.  Make that change, and then uncomment `$("#refresh").html(data)`.  if data is being returned, you see your #refresh tag being updated.

Comment: so your code should be like:
    (function worker() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8088/Login.do', 
            success: function(data) {
               $("#refresh").html(data);
                // alert(data);
            },
           complete: function() {

                //alert("refresh");
                // 
               // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
               setTimeout(worker, 5000);
           }
       });
   })();`

Comment: I have tried that but page refreshes but java script does not refresh ..So values are not appearing ..

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an AJAX request every 5 seconds. The url seems to me to not be right. In JSP, you either make an AJAX request to a servlet, to a JSP page, or to some other resource. I don't know what .do is.

Check out BalusC explanation here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

You do not fully grasp what and how AJAX works. You should learn more about this.

[Here is a video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VgHJCAKZZQ)